# Hadoop Error: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to run a MapReduce program in Java with 2 input files and also with 2 mappers.

Below is the code:

```
public class CounterMapper {
    public static class MyMap1 extends
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable> {
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String[] line = value.toString().split("\t");

            int age = Integer.parseInt(line[26]);

            context.write(new Text(line[7]), new LongWritable(age));
        }
    }

    public static class MyMap2 extends Mapper {
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String[] line = value.toString().split("\t");
            int age = Integer.parseInt(line[26]);
            context.write(new Text(line[7]), new LongWritable(age));
        }
    }

    public static class MyRed extends
            Reducer<Text, LongWritable, Text, LongWritable> {
        String line = null;

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<LongWritable> values,
                Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            for (LongWritable value : values) {
                line = value.toString();
            }
            context.write(key, new LongWritable());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Job job = new Job(conf, "ProjectQuestion2");
        job.setJarByClass(CounterMapper.class);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));

        job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
        job.setMapperClass(MyMap1.class);
        job.setMapperClass(MyMap2.class);
        job.setReducerClass(MyRed.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]),
                TextInputFormat.class, MyMap1.class);
        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]),
                TextInputFormat.class, MyMap2.class);

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

and after running the job i get the below error:

> INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486434709675_0016_m_000000_2,
>   Status : FAILED Error: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from
>   map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1073)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:715)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:124)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.DelegatingMapper.run(DelegatingMapper.java:55)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

Any input is appreciated...Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Its likely that its using the `map()` method in the base class `Mapper` instead of yours. Since this is an identity mapper (pass through) which would match up with the error you're seeing.

I would do a few things:

1. In `MyMap2` change `Mapper` to `Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable>`.
2. Make sure your `map()` methods are overriding the base `Mapper` class by add the `@Override` annotation to them.

You can also (improvements):

1. Change `Job job = new Job(conf, "ProjectQuestion2");` to `Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "ProjectQuestion2");` to remove the deprication warning.
2. `job.setMapOutputKeyClass()` and `job.setMapOutputValueClass()` are set twice, you can remove one pair.